# Understanding For-in Loop

Tags: javascript

Here I have variable that has an object whose one value is an array of objects
eg.

```
var test = { "key1": val1,
"key2": [{"a":1,
        "b":[{},{}]
        },
        {"a":1,
        "b":[{},{}]
        }]
   };
```

I am now unable to understand why following piece of code iterates two times. Shouldnt it just iterate once as only 1 array element is present?

code snippet:

```
for( index in test.key2)
```

Comment: is this some kind of a joke or something ?

Comment: There are definitely two elements: the first is `{"a":1, "b": [{},{}]}` and the second is the same as that. Does your question have something to do with the fact that the two elements look the same?

Comment: `key2` is an array with two items. But don't use for/in for arrays. In Javascript you should use the index numbers to iterate over an array. for/in is for objects. See "Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is where good indentation is key.

```
var test = {
    "key1": val1,
    "key2": [
        {
            "a":1,
            "b":[{},{}]
        },
        {
            "a":1,
            "b":[{},{}]
        }
    ]
};
```

Here you can clearly see that it in fact has 2 items.

Answer (score 0):

Because `test.key2` is a `array` having two `elements`, So it will iterate two times.

Check `test.key2.length;`